# I am getting a NULL object on a Action response in Zapier. This is causing the action to fail and causing Zapier to not renew the auth token

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am not using CLI but the Platform UI.  I have an integration that gets an Auth token and is good for 3600 seconds.  I execute my action within those 3600 seconds and all works fine.   Any execution outside the 3600 seconds fail b/c the token is no longer valid.  My understanding is Zapier will refresh that token on a failed response but the response must return a valid object.   My response returns no object but a status of 401.  Since there is no object returned i get the below response.  I have put some console.log in to see if the code even gets to the ".then" but i never get anything written to the console so i feel like the ".then" is never executed.  I have added the ".catch" as well but the code never seems to get there either..

Result from `creates.createWorkItem.operation.perform` must be a single object.
We got `null`.

code:

```
return z.request(options)
   .then((response) => {
   z.console.log('Test',response.data);
   response.throwForStatus();
   const results = response.json;

   // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

   return results;
});
```

Code with catch:

```
return z.request(options)
   .then((response) => {
   z.console.log('Test',response.data);
   response.throwForStatus();
   const results = response.json;

   // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

   return results;
})
.catch(error => {
   return {"contactId":0};
 });
```

Comment: So if you think `z... .then` is not executing, could you validate `z` using a ternary operator? 
`let z = z ? z : {z: 'default'}`

Comment: There's enough here that it's probably worth contacting [developer support](https://developer.zapier.com/contact) so that they can take a look at everything.